# INNODB pool buffer size increase results in high CPU usage

Tags: mysql, cpu, innodb

I recently increased the pool buffer size and the database has slowed down considerably. Very high CPU usage as well. Can someone please advise on what could be causing this?

[image]

Comment: Did you also increase the log buffer to 25% of the pool buffer like it is advised in the manual?

Comment: Thank you, no I haven't done that. Shall try that out!

Comment: How did you measure "the database has slowed down considerably"? Actually, an increased cpu usage can be a good sign - as it reduces the time that the cpu has to idle at around 0% while reading data from disk (instead of having it in the buffer pool).

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  What is the slowest query?  Is the slowlog enabled?  Was there any swapping?  High CPU usually indicates poor indexing or poor formulation of a query.